# Replace and clone existing ssd drive from Ubuntu live

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd

I have the following system:

- SSD 120gb -> Has windows & ubuntu dual boot, grub
- HDD 1tb -> It looks like it's the one containing the MBR

I want to replace the SSD with a bigger one (500gb) so I disonnected the HDD and was planning to clone the 120gb ssd to the 500gb ssd but oops, once I get past GRUB the OS is not found.

What is the best approach to do this? Clone the first ssd into the new ssd via ubuntu live and then changing UUID's or something? Will it screw my grub?

Comment: Ubuntu live has a clone feature?

Comment: Tools like gparted, gnome-disks or dd are included in the image and can be used in ubuntu live. I already cloned it with dd.

Comment: How did you clone it using `dd`?  You will need to clone the entire drive and not just partitions.  Cloning the entire drive will copy everything, including UUIDs, from one drive to the other.  Very similar to how a program like Clonezilla will do it.

Comment: If you use dd to clone drive, you cannot reboot with both drives connected. Duplicate UUIDs are not allowed. Well it may boot, but you will not know which system it is using as it depends on UEFI/BIOS on which it sees first. And if updates may then occur to wrong system. If new drive works, then you can change UUIDs on old SSD or totally repartition it. Is it UEFI or BIOS and MBR or gpt partitioned?

Comment: As it was a replacement (see title) everything worked perfectly just cloning the entire drive into the other drive. Didn't had to do any additional steps except removing the old one and pluggin the new one instead.